# Fastest way of transferring an unstructured collection of S3 files to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

If we are downloading an entire virtual directory then there is the method `MultipleFileDownload(...)` from TransferManager. However `MultipleFileDownload(...)` does not support downloading an arbitrary list of S3 files objects. What is the best way of downloading such a large list of files?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to transfer S3 files to EC2's local directory, you can just use aws cli command on your EC2 as follows:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucketname> <local directory> --recursive --include "*"
```